# The type of a spatial column cannot be changed (Requested changing type from "geometry" to "geometry" for column "center_location" in table "parking")

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine, postgis

I use Symfony. I have custom type for doctrine, which extends from Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Types\GeometryType (jsor/doctrine-postgis library):

```
use Jsor\Doctrine\PostGIS\Types\GeometryType;

class PointType extends GeometryType
{
    public const POINT = 'point_type';

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): ?Point
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }
        $pattern = '/POINT\(([-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*) ([-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*)\)/';

        if (preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches)) {
            $latitude = (float) $matches[1];
            $longitude = (float) $matches[2];

            return new Point($latitude, $longitude);
        } else {
            throw new \DomainException('Incorrect string');
        }
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): ?string
    {
        /** @var Point $value */
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }
        return sprintf('POINT(%f %f)', $value->getLatitude(), $value->getLongitude());
    }

    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}`
```

My Entity field:

`#[ORM\Column(type: PointType::POINT, nullable: true)] protected ?Point $centerLocation = null;`

When I create the first migration - it's ok (The field is created with type geometry(geometry, 0)), but if I try to continue work with my DB (update, new migrations, diff) then I get error:

```
`The type of a spatial column cannot be changed (Requested changing type from "geometry" to "geometry" for column "center_location" in table "parking")  `
```

I tried to do without inheritance and put the library methods into my custom PointType, but the error is still present.

Has anyone encountered this? Any idea how to fix it? I would be grateful for your answer.

**UPD:** My doctrine.dbal.types:

```
point_type: 'App\Entity\PropertyType\PointType'
polygon_type: 'App\Entity\PropertyType\PolygonType'`
```

Fields in migration look like:

```
`center_location geometry(GEOMETRY, 0) DEFAULT NULL, polygon geometry(GEOMETRY, 0) DEFAULT NULL`
```

There are SQL conversion methods inside the library and they look like this:

```
public function convertToPHPValueSQL($sqlExpr, $platform): string
{
    return sprintf('ST_AsEWKT(%s)', $sqlExpr);
}

public function convertToDatabaseValueSQL($sqlExpr, AbstractPlatform $platform): string
{
    return sprintf('ST_GeomFromEWKT(%s)', $sqlExpr);
}
```

Comment: Show the migration since there's a problem with that it seems. And the `doctrine.dbal.types` config (https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types). I used this kind of type (also for `Shape`) in a project in the past and looking at code from there you're missing `convertToPHPValueSQL` and `convertToDatabaseValueSQL`, but it shouldn't matter for this error. The rest is more or less as I had it.

Comment: What does the migration do exactly? Change the column types? If so, what type were they before? That error strongly suggests that you're trying to change `geometry` type of column even though it's already defined as such. And you can't alter columns with `geometry` type.

Comment: @Destroy666. No, it's creating a table with this fields. Next, when I try to run any doctrine command (e.g. doc:sch:upd --force), I get this error

Comment: No idea then if that's the only occurence and it's not altered anywhere else. But quick google yielded this result, maybe also you have a similar issue? https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis/issues/6#issuecomment-383649966

Comment: @Destroy666. I saw this solution, but I don't have an xml import file.   Thanks for trying, I will keep looking for a solution :)